# Get own space on server with PHP

Tags: php, apache, webserver

I have own space on private serwer FTP.

This is:

**/home/poker/my_space**

and i have there my site:

**/home/poker/my_space/my_site**

i have also folder images:

**/home/poker/my_space/images**

If i login then i am on server in space:

**/home/poker/**

here i have two catalogs: my_space and images

so how can i get this place with PHP functions?

```
$my_place = ??? dir? $_SERVER ?? __FILE__ ??

echo $my_place;
```

$my_place should return **/home/poker/**

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you set as document root in your webserver.
e.g. find documentroot `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];`

use it e.g.
`include("$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']/../something.php");`

Comment: but how can i make it with PHP?

Answer (score 0):

you can try using this for getting the root folder of your hosting account.

```
$my_place = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
echo $my_place;
```

Please take a look at this - http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php for more information.

Comment: this return me **/home/poker/my_space/** instead of **/home/poker/**

Comment: I dont think you will be able to access files outside your root folder using relative path. you could always try using the 

$path = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/'.'path to the folder you want';

Am confused though!